# How do I set the application name when connecting to IBM MQ using pymqi?

Tags: pymqi

I have a Python client application that consumes from an IBM MQ queue.  We are using the pymqi client, with MQCNO_CLIENT_BINDING and MQCNO_RECONNECT options specified so MQ can balance multiple instances of the clients across queue managers in an MQ cluster.  The part I'm missing is how to set the application name.  With other client packages (e.g., NodeJS) there is a connection parameter that is passed at the time MQCONN is called.

If I look on the MQ server side I see the name being set as 'python3'.  I assume this is some default coming in from the client.  Is there a way to explicitly set the name using pymqi?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally with language bindings built on the C MQI you ought to be able to set the MQCNO.ApplName. But the Python library might not be sufficiently up-to-date to recognise that field. Instead, you ought to be able to set an environment variable - MQAPPLNAME - before you do the MQCONN.

See https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/ibm-mq/9.3?topic=languages-using-application-name-in-supported-programming